# How can I soundproof my door?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

This is the kind of door I have.

[image: Door]

But I don't know what's an effective way to soundproof it.

As much as possible I don't wanna spend much money that could reach $20 and above.

I don't have that much budget

Comment: You really can't soundproof a lightweight door.

Answer (score 2):

Suspend a heavy rolled-up quilt (get it from a flea market or discount re-seller) above the door. When you are inside, unfurl the quilt so it covers the entire door and frame. probably your best option for the money you are willing to spend.

Comment: Tacked on inch thick styrofoam is another option. The pink stuff can be had cheap at a home supply store.

Answer (score 1):

Thin weather-stripping applied to the top & right side door stop moldings & to the left door jamb beside the door stop molding. Frost King's 3/8's Triple Rib self adhesive stuff works great. Sound transmission is largely stopped when air transmission is stopped.